# Can not create custom repository in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have TrainRepository which extends JpaRepository and it works good.
But when I create CustomRepository and TrainRepository extends CustomRepository, Spring throws UnsatisfiedDependencyException.

TrainRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface TrainRepository  extends JpaRepository<Train,Long>,CustomRepository {

    @Query("select new ua.nulp.company.traincompany.dto.TrainsDto(t.id,t.name,t.trainType) from Train t")
    List<TrainsDto> findTrains();

    @Query("select new ua.nulp.company.traincompany.dto.TrainDto(t.name,t.trainType) from Train t where t.id=:id")
    TrainDto findDtoTrainById(@Param("id")Long id);

    @Query("select distinct t.trainType from Train t")
    List<TrainType> getTrainTypes();

    @Query(value = "SELECT t.name as name, sum(c.number_seats) as seats FROM train t JOIN train_car c ON " +
            "t.id = c.train_id WHERE t.id = 2 GROUP BY t.name;",nativeQuery = true)
    TrainSeatsDto getAmountPassengersSeats(@Param("id")Long id);
}
```

CustomRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface CustomRepository {
    String getTrainNameByID(Long id);
}
```

CustomRepositoryImp:

```
@Component
public class CustomRepositoryImp implements CustomRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public String getTrainNameByID(Long id) {
        return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT t.name FROM Train t WHERE t.id =:id", String.class)
                .setParameter("id",id)
                .getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-11-19 21:17:13.006 ERROR 15300 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'trainController' defined in file [C:\Users\ASUS\OneDrive\Документи\Java\enterprise\programs\TrainCompany\target\classes\ua\nulp\company\traincompany\controller\TrainController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'trainRepository' defined in ua.nulp.company.traincompany.repository.TrainRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.lang.String ua.nulp.company.traincompany.repository.CustomRepository.getTrainNameByID(java.lang.Long); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.lang.String ua.nulp.company.traincompany.repository.CustomRepository.getTrainNameByID(java.lang.Long)! No property 'ID' found for type 'Train' Did you mean ''id''; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.lang.String ua.nulp.company.traincompany.repository.CustomRepository.getTrainNameByID(java.lang.Long)! No property 'ID' found for type 'Train' Did you mean ''id''
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at ua.nulp.company.traincompany.TrainCompanyApplication.main(TrainCompanyApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
```

Comment: it can be diamond problem, because both interfaces have same method with same name. https://www.javatpoint.com/what-is-diamond-problem-in-java